# Can't receive data, ajax, javascript, jquery, php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to send data that i got from a jquery call and now i want to save it to a file on the server with php.

```
function getSVG(){
   svghead = svghead + $('#test').html();

   $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            data: svghead,
            url: "xyz.php",
             success:function(data){
                 .....
            }
        });
    }
```

and in php my code is:

```
<?php
   header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 

   $data = $_POST['data'];

   $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
   fwrite($myfile, $data);
   fclose($myfile);
?>
```

but the created file never contains any value. it s just empty. as far as i tested, i guess it is just a syntax mistake but where or what is wrong? thx for any help

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect? What does your server's error log say?

Comment: How are you telling to PHP that there is a `data` paramenter posted? Try `data: { data: svghead } ` in your ajax call.

Comment: i am simulating with xampp, firebug doesnt show any erros. the file is created successfully but it s just empty

Comment: @DominikZinser nice! Added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the parameter name in order to PHP recognize it:

```
data: {
    data: svghead
}
```

With the object above you're sending a `data` paramenter with the value equal to your `svghead` variable.